# How will I get the column data type of dataset in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Want to compare the data types of two dataset's in spark using java.

Comment: Elaborate in more details. In which API? Java? The best way is to share your code because the code is our common language.

Comment: Hi Soheil , Here we want to check the schema of the existing table with the new table. if there is any change in the schema we need to drop of the existing table and create a new table and this comparsion based on the column name and column type

Answer (score 0):

There is a method called dtypes(). See the docs here: [Dataset JavaDoc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#dtypes())

I think this method can do your job.